# angular 2 forms not working after making all the validations

Tags: angular

I have a component with three input fields and all of them are required fields .I have added required in all the input elements,put them all under a form tag  .On  click of the button i have to send values of those 3 fields in some web service.I have added a disabled class on that button if any of the fields are empty but it's not working .I am able to navigate to the next page even if all the fields are empty so it's not an issue with one particular input field which means my form validation is itself not working

cardDetail.component html

```
    <app-header></app-header>
<div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
<h3 style="font-family: Lucida Console serif;color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.71);font-size: 17px;text-align: left;">Enter Payment Details</h3>
<p id ="plain">We require your bank details to transfer the <br>claim amount to you.<br>
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #carddetailform ="ngForm" id="ngForm">


  <div class="form-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" [(ngModel)] = "name"  placeholder="Full Name" required>
  <div [hidden]="name.valid || name.pristine"
     class="alert alert-danger">
  Name is required
</div><br><br>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ifsc" name="ifsc" (keyup)=  "onlatestinputchange($event)" [(ngModel)] = ifsc   [value]="ifsc || '' " placeholder="IFSC Code" required>
  <div [hidden]="ifsc.valid || ifsc.pristine"
     class="alert alert-danger">
  IFSC Code is required
</div>

  </div>
  <p id ="message">Don't know your IFSC Code? That's okay, <a (click)="openDialog()">Find out here!</a><br><br>
<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" id="keyword" class="form-control" name="bankname" [(ngModel)]= "query"  (keyup)="filter()" placeholder="BANK"  />
<div [hidden]="ifsc.valid || ifsc.pristine"
     class="alert alert-danger">
  Bank Name is required
</div>
</div>

  <!--</div>-->


<div class="filter-select" *ngIf="filteredList.length > 0">
  <ul  *ngFor="let item of filteredList" class="filter-select-list"><li class="artist-name">

    <a (click)="select(item)">{{item}}</a>
  </li>

</ul>
</div>

 <button type="submit"   [disabled]="!carddetailform.form.valid" form="ngForm" id ="button"class="form-control"  routerLink="/endOfSurvey">Send Bank Details</button> 
<!-- <button type="submit" id ="button" class="form-control" routerLink="/endOfSurvey" >Send Bank Details</button> -->
  </form>
</div></div></div>
```

Added 2 lines in  my component.ts file

```
submitted = false;
onSubmit() { this.submitted = true; }
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have 'spaces' between your attribute-value-assignments on the template in multiple places. Fix those. For example,

```
#carddetailform = "ngForm" ===> #carddetailform="ngForm"

name ="ifsc"               ===> name="ifsc"
```

likewise in many places, clean them first.

Then change your `button` from,

```
< <button type="submit"   [disabled]="!carddetailform.form.valid" form="ngForm" id ="button"class="form-control" routerLink="/endOfSurvey" >Send Bank Details</button>
```

to,

```
<button type="submit"   [disabled]="!carddetailform.valid" id="button" class="form-control" [routerLink]="carddetailform.valid ? '/endOfSurvey' : null" >Send Bank Details</button>
```

See if it works.

Comment: if i am keeping me third input field empty its still navigating

Comment: That is because you have used `[ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"`. If you remove it then it should work. The presence of this option detaches that formControl from the main parent formGroup.

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work .Can you suggest some other options?

Comment: Could you show me your latest code as of now which has the problem? I can try and see what's wrong with it

Comment: sure i will do that and i have one more issue .I am trying to show error messages for those 3 input fields if they are empty and that's also not working .It is giving me error that cannot read valid of undefined when i am using <div [hidden]="name.valid || name.pristine"
     class="alert alert-danger">
  Name is required
</div> this code